# Unable to load wsdl file from android browser

Tags: web-services, weblogic, oracle-adf-mobile

I Develop a `webservice` from a java class using `JDeveloper`.and deploy it on my local `weblogic` server. i can access the `wsdl` directly from my browser . but when i try to access it from my android phone web browser it is not loading it.however i can connect to my local `weblogic` server via phone. here is the `url` of my`wsdl`
http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:7101/WebServices-Services-context-root/BooksPort?WSDL

Error Message

```
You tried to access the address which is currently unavailable.make sure that the web address is correctly spelt and punctuated then try reloading again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is 7101 is the right port for you wsdl?

Try 7001 and let me know

Comment: I tried it using 7001 it's not loading it. but when deploy my app in my phone based on that webservice it's working

Answer (score 0):

Are other sites like google.com opening up on your mobile browser? You  may require proxy settings to access the WSDL.

Comment: This seems better-suited as a comment.